# Android: Creating a new instance of an intent/activity

Tags: android, android-intent, instance

I have a slight problem.

I am trying to make a question list application, and therefor when I press the next button I want the new question to load in to the QuestionActivity class, and when te previous button is pressed I want the previous question to come up.

The problemen is that I can't figure out how to make a new instance of the QuestionActivity when I press the button..

```
ImageButton arrowLButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.arrowLButton);
    arrowLButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
    {
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            if(pos >= 0)
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent(QuestionActivity.this, QuestionActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                setPos(getPos() - 1);
                setQuestion();
            }
        }
    });
```

Above are the actions of the button.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: your code seems to be ok, but you should call your functions before starting new activity

Comment: When I call the functions before (or after) intitially it changes to the next question, but directly it switches back to the inital value of "pos" which is the first question

Comment: because you want to pass "pos" to the new activity, so you should make the variable "pos" to be an application level variable, or in the simplest way, you can use putExtra function of "intent"

Answer (score 0):

Should that fail you for some reason, you can always call your activity using its package name, though it's a rather roundabout way of accomplishing your goal.

```
PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();  //The getPackageManager() method must be called from inside the activity
Intent intent = pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage("your.package.name");
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: When I call the functions before (or after) intitially it changes to the next question, but directly it switches back to the inital value of "pos" which is the first question

Comment: @eurynox That's because by starting the intent over again, you are restarting the app and wiping your variables clean. To solve this, you could either restructure your app so that it doesn't have to restart itself, or you could make your variables persist by saving them to a text file. The second option, however, is more like a bandaid and probably shouldn't be your permanent fix.